# SetPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page)' is obsolete error - Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a universal application with Xamarin Forms

I get the warning

Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.SetPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page)' is obsolete

Has anyone come across this?

The code is shown below

```
public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);    
        SetPage (App.GetMainPage ());
    }
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forms 1.3.1 supports a new Application class that has a MainPage property, which allows you to set the App start page in a single location (rather than once per platform).

```
public class App : Application // superclass new in 1.3
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage {...}; // property new in 1.3
    }
```

A [Migration Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating-xamarin-forms-apps/) is available which outlines all of the changes you will need to make in your app for the new API.

Comment: This has killed my ios app I have UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate" in main cs which was generated.  Now UIApplication is not available so what am I supposed to replace this line with?  I cant see any mention of that in the guide, and without knowing that my app wont run?  I cant just change it to remove a parameter (the null one) because that cause a stack overflow error?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything in Main.cs.  Did it fix your Android issue?  If so, it might be better to create a new Question for the iOS issue so you can post a clear example of the problem.

Comment: The guide stated that all elements should be updated. The android warning has gone now thanks I will raise a new question I really hope someone can help cos this has stopped me in my tracks